# How can I fix my re compile statement in Python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a text file and I am using re to locate a specific section of text (a list containing water usage in different towns) and putting the information into a pandas dataframe. The text list is ordered using letters e.g (a), (b), (c) etc. The code works fine and returns all the information I need into the dataframe up until the ordering switches to double letters e.g (aa), (ab), (ac) etc.

How can I fix my re statement so that it also works for double lettered indexes in the text list?

Here is the code:

```
pattern = regex.compile('\d+ (?=ML\/year)|(?<= in the |the )[\w \/\(\)]+')
    columns = ('Water Usage', 'Town')

    res = [dict(zip(columns, pattern.findall(line))) for line in finalText.splitlines() if pattern.match(line)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(res)

    return df
```

And here is an example of the text:

```
(w) 218 ML/year in the Murrumbidgee I Water Source,
(x) 133 ML/year in the Murrumbidgee II Water Source,
(y) 116 ML/year in the Murrumbidgee III Water Source,
(z) 73 ML/year in the Murrumbidgee North Water Source,
(aa) 476 ML/year in the Murrumbidgee Western Water Source,
(ab) 92 ML/year in the Muttama Water Source,
(ac) 150 ML/year in the Numeralla East Water Source,
```

As I said, it works for all the rows with single letter indexes but doesn't for double letters.

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. Your regex does not even match the letters: https://regex101.com/r/0Z6wAQ/1

Comment: As the comment above said, the regex is not even touching the letters. Here's a tip how I deal with complex regexes - interactive tools like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) allow you to visualize how your regex is matching your input data.

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract ?

Comment: I want to extract the ML usage for each water source into a dataframe but for some reason it isn't working for any indexes with two letters and I have no idea why.

Comment: I think the issue might be that you're using match() instead of search()

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://regex101.com/ or https://regexr.com/ to troubleshoot your regular expression.  Here's one that matches the key components.

`^\([^)]+\)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*\/year)\s+in the\s+(.*),`

Answer (score 0):

Python `re` module doesn't allow variable width pattern in look behind assertions.
correcting it, if you had used `search()` instead of `match()` it would have worked.

```py
def create_df(finalText):
    pattern = re.compile('\d+ (?=ML\/year)|(?<= in the)[\w \/\(\)]+')
    columns = ('Water Usage', 'Town')
    res = [dict(zip(columns, pattern.findall(line))) for line in finalText.splitlines() if pattern.search(line)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(res)
    return df
```